# How to add text in the center of the polygon in Gmap.net

Tags: c#, winforms, maps, gis, gmap.net

I want to add a text in the center position of the already zone polygon. I am able to show the polygon and also able to get the center position of the Polygon but I am not able to add the name of the polygon.

I have done following so far :

```
        List<PointLatLng> listVertexPoints = Get_VertexPointsFromString(zoneVertex);
        foreach (PointLatLng vertex in listVertexPoints)
        {
            GMapMarkerCircle circleVertex = new GMapMarkerCircle(vertex, 1);
            circleVertex.Radius = 1;
            circleVertex.IsVisible = false;
            overlay.Markers.Add(circleVertex);
        }

        GMapPolygon zonePolygon;
        zonePolygon = new GMapPolygon(listVertexPoints, zoneName);
        zonePolygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
        zonePolygon.Stroke = new Pen(zoneBoundaryColor, 1);
        zonePolygon.IsFilled = true;
        zonePolygon.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        overlay.Polygons.Add(zonePolygon);

        PointLatLng centerPoint = GetZoneCenter(listVertexPoints);

        private PointLatLng GetZoneCenter(List<PointLatLng> vertexes)
        {
          PointLatLng centerPoint = new PointLatLng();
          int sum = 0;
          double lat = 0;
          double lng = 0;
          foreach (var point in vertexes)
          {
              sum += 1;
              lat += point.Lat;
              lng += point.Lng;
          }
          lat = lat / sum;
          lng = lng / sum;
          centerPoint.Lat = lat;
          centerPoint.Lng = lng;
          return centerPoint;
      }
        var labelMarker = new GmapMarkerWithLabel(centerPoint, zoneName, GMarkerGoogleType.blue);
        markerOverlay.Markers.Add(labelMarker);
        this.MainMap.Overlays.Add(overlay);
```

The above code showed a label marker but it does not appear in the correct place. Also, if you have any other way to show text within Polygon then you are most welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want the whole text to be inside the polygone? If so you need to change the font size to fit the text. If not is the font size fixed?

Comment: Can you clarify your question by an image for the wrong label place and another image for the required correct place

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this after some effort. I am calling SetCenterFromVertices() method inside UpdateGraphicsPath() method of GMapPolygon.cs class and uses graphic's drawString method to draw the text in the desired location. This is required as it is possible that on resize of a polygon; we need to change the position of the text too.

```
    #region use this line inside OnRender(Graphics g) method
    g.DrawString(this.Name, font_PolygonName, Brushes.AliceBlue, (float)center.X, (float)center.Y);
    #endregion

    private Point_ center = new Point_();

    void SetCenterFromVertices()
    {
        List<Point_> lstPoint = new List<Point_>();
        foreach (var p in LocalPoints)
        {
            Point_ np = new Point_();
            np.X = p.X;
            np.Y = p.Y;
            lstPoint.Add(np);
        }
        center = Compute2DPolygonCentroid(lstPoint);
    }

    static Point_ Compute2DPolygonCentroid(List<Point_> vertices)
    {
        Point_ centroid = new Point_() { X = 0.0, Y = 0.0 };
        double signedArea = 0.0;
        double x0 = 0.0;
        double y0 = 0.0;
        double x1 = 0.0;
        double y1 = 0.0;
        double a = 0.0;

        // For all vertices except last
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < vertices.Count - 1; ++i)
        {
            x0 = vertices[i].X;
            y0 = vertices[i].Y;
            x1 = vertices[i + 1].X;
            y1 = vertices[i + 1].Y;
            a = x0 * y1 - x1 * y0;
            signedArea += a;
            centroid.X += (x0 + x1) * a;
            centroid.Y += (y0 + y1) * a;
        }

        // Do last vertex
        x0 = vertices[i].X;
        y0 = vertices[i].Y;
        x1 = vertices[0].X;
        y1 = vertices[0].Y;
        a = x0 * y1 - x1 * y0;
        signedArea += a;
        centroid.X += (x0 + x1) * a;
        centroid.Y += (y0 + y1) * a;

        signedArea *= 0.5;
        centroid.X /= (6 * signedArea);
        centroid.Y /= (6 * signedArea);

        return centroid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I only made an overlay with some graphics (not with printet text), but you could check if you have done all the following steps:

1.: Have you initialized your GMapControl with `mapControl.MarkersEnabled = true;`?

2.: Have you added your overlay to the control? `mapControl.Overlays.Add(overlay);`

3.: Have you added markers to your overlay? `overlay.Markers.Add(marker);`
    I add them after adding the overlay to the control. maybe that makes a difference?

4.: Have you overridden the OnRender(Graphics g) method in your GmapMarkerWithLabel?
    Example (not checked):

```
private string zoneName = "Name from Constructor";
public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
{
    base.OnRender(g);

    // Measure the size of the text. 
    // You might want to add some extra space around your text. 
    // MeasureString is quite tricky...
    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(this.zoneName, SystemFonts.DefaultFont);

    // Get LocalPoint (your LatLng coordinate in pixel)
    Point localPosition = this.LocalPosition;

    // Move the localPosition by the half size of the text.
    PointF textPosition = new PointF((float)(localPosition.X - textSize.Width / 2f),(float)(localPosition.Y - textSize.Height / 2f));

    // Draw Background
    g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, new RectangleF(textPosition, textSize));
    g.DrawString(this.zoneName, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Color.Black, textPosition);
}
```

I hope this helps you to get going...